# How to center between layouts in relative layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to place the cardview in the center of the ImageView like this:

[image]

If I use android:layout_below it will be like this:

[image]

This is my code:

[image]

Comment: This is easily done with ConstraintLayout. Just constrain `top` and `bottom` of `CardView` to the bottom of `background_image`

Answer (score 0):

Please read [how to write a good question first.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Regarding your question this bit of code might help you try with a negative value of `translationY`

for example:

```
android:translationY="-50dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, Rearranging the location of the layout, image or textview comes under the topic of alignment.
so if you want to put your image src in middle vertically, you should use the code below written

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

and for center Horizontally

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

or else, I think we can also use gravity to put every element in mid of parent layout like `android:gravity="center"`
Hoping that it will be helpful.